# How can I find the order of a group of integers without altering their order in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to find out the order of a group of an undefined amount of integers.

For example it could be {30,60,10,100,20,50,110} however I don't want to sort them, I want to change them (or create a new array) with the order of them.

For example the array given earlier would turn to {3,5,1,6,2,4,7}. This is because 30 is the first number in the array and is the 3rd smallest number in the array. And 60 is the 5th smallest etc. Therefore I have the new ascending order of the numbers without altering their positions in the array.

Comment: How does `30` turn into `3` and `110` into `6`? What's the logic? What's the operation that produces that result?

Comment: What if the numbers aren't unique? What should {10, 10, 10} return? {1, 1, 1} or something different?

Comment: Please elaborate your questions.The relation between original array and the new array is not clear.

Comment: *ascending order of the numbers without altering their positions in the array* this is clearly impossible for your test case.

Comment: @ernest_k 30 is the 3rd lowest value. So if it would be ordered the 30 would be at place 3 (or 2 if you wan't to use the array indexes starting at 0)

Comment: Ernest_K 30 turns into 3 because it is the 3rd lowest number in the array and 110 turns into 6 as it is the 6th lowest number in the array

Comment: So, what have you tried? I would recommend using two arrays, 1 original and 1 sorted array.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS {10,10,10} should return {1,2,3}

Comment: `{3,4,1,5,2,3,6}`? Why do you have 3 in there twice - for 30 and for 50? Did you mean `{3,5,1,6,2,4,7}`?

Comment: @jaroslaw pawlak. Yes i did I’m sorry about that

Comment: Since this is obviously homework I think you should tell us if there are any restrictions on a solution like are Collection types allowed or streams etc.

Comment: looks like he wants an output where if `input[n] > input[n+1]` then `output[n] > output[n+1]`, same with `<`

Comment: @failingcoder but I need to preserve the order of the original array. They can’t be in the sorted order

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this is not homework so there are no restrictions

Comment: @Ilan Could you explain in more details in your question how you get the resulting array? Or I am afraid that question will end up being closed because it is very unclear at the moment

Comment: @Bentaye I have tried to now make it more clear. Is that ok?

Comment: @Ilan That's why I suggested a second array. You have one **original, not modified** array, and a second, **different, sorted array.**

Comment: @Ilan Yes lot clearer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how readable and efficient this is, but I wanted to try doing it like this. It creates a stream of integers from the range `[0, numbers.length - 1]` and sorts them using the numbers as indices to the original array. It adds 1 in the end to get the range to start from 1.

```
int[] numbers = {30, 60, 10, 100, 20, 50, 110};
int[] order = IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> numbers[e]))
        .mapToInt(e -> e + 1).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(order)); // [3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 7]
```

Comment: That's smart! You could simplify slightly: `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> numbers[i]))`.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @radulfr thank you so much! This is perfect and exactly what I needed. I really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort them.
You can't find the order of things without sorting them.

Just make a copy and sort it.